# ASP.Net grid with frozen headers, columns and lots of data

Tags: asp.net, frozen-columns

I am in need of a control that will give me input functionality where the user will get a few locked columns on the left and will be able to enter some values into text boxes to the right (for example a row value may be a name, and the columns would be each day of a month). As the user inputs values and scrolls to the right, the first couple of columns on the left would say locked (i.e. in view) and as the user scrolls down the list the headers would stay in view.

I have done exhaustive analysis of JQuery fixed header/column plugins, and while many of them were promising, none of them worked well once there were many rows (> 100) and many columns (> 15 or so). They would all start to freeze the browser (especially in IE).

I am more than happy to buy a commercial control that meets my needs, but I haven't been able to find any.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Did you try http://jlynch7.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-frozen-columns.html or https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid In my opinion it is awsome!